# Is There a way to treat a large file?

Tags: apache-camel

I m using apache Camel to treat files.

However, i m asking if i can split a file depending on the number of byte.

For exemple , if i have a file with a size like 1 GO, is that possible to read it by block of 10 MO. (with a parameter that defines the size of a block)

Is there a component Camel EIP able to do this ?

I have tried with stream-caching but nothing happened.

```
    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" trace="true">

    <properties>
        <property key="CamelCachedOutputStreamBufferSize" value="1024"/>
    </properties>


    <route id="READ-FILE-STREAM-CACHE" streamCache="true">
        <from uri="file:src/data?noop=true"/>
        <bean ref="readBean" method="readFileStream"/>
        <to uri="file:src/out"/>
    </route>

</camelContext>
```

Thanks

Comment: Already posted on the Camel user forum / mailing list where its answered

Comment: @ClausIbsen and here is the link for the rest of the camel fan club: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Is-There-a-way-to-treat-a-large-file-td5774055.html